# Why is my head coming up null when I try to insert into LinkedList (ignore the name DoublyLinkedList it's not one yet)?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

Here's my node class:

```
package esp.types;

public class Node<E> {
    public E value;
    public Node<E> next;

    public Node(E value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public Node(E value, Node<E> next) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

And here's my DoublyLinkedList class:

```
package esp.impls;

import esp.impls.LinkedListBase;
import esp.types.Node;

public class DoublyLinkedList<E> extends LinkedListBase<E> {
    public Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> currPos;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        super();
    }
    public Node<E> getHead() {
        return this.head;
    }
    public void insert(E item) {
        if (this.head == null) {
            this.head = new Node<E>(item);
            return;
        }
        Node<E> temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = new Node<E>(item);
    }

    public void delete(E item) {
        System.out.println("built");
    }

    public int getLength() {
        Node<E> temp = head;
        int count = 0;
        while (temp != null) {
            count++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int searchItem(E item) {
        return 0;

    }

    public E getNextItem() {
        E please = head.value;
        return please;
    }

    public void resetList() {
        System.out.print("built");
    }

}
```

And here's where I test:

```
package esp.tests;

import esp.impls.DoublyLinkedList;
import esp.impls.LinkedListBase;
import esp.types.Node;

public class ListTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedListBase<Integer> list1 = new DoublyLinkedList<Integer>();
        list1 = testLinkedInsert(list1);
        System.out.println(list1.head);
    }
    public static void testLinked(LinkedListBase<Integer> list) {
        testLinkedInsert(list);
        testLinkedDelete(list);
        testLinkedLength(list);
    }

    public static LinkedListBase<Integer> testLinkedInsert(LinkedListBase<Integer> listl) {
        System.out.println("Testing Insert");
        listl.insert(10);
        printList(listl);
        System.out.println("Done!\n");
        return listl;
    }

    public static void testLinkedDelete(LinkedListBase<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println("Testing Delete");
        list.delete(10);
        list.delete(20);
        list.delete(0);
        System.out.println("Done!\n");
    }

    public static void testLinkedLength(LinkedListBase<Integer> list) {
        System.out.println("Testing Length");
        list.getLength();
        System.out.println("Done!\n");
    }

    public static void printList(LinkedListBase<Integer> list) {
        Node<Integer> temp = list.head;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print("[");
            }
            //System.out.print(temp.value);
            if (i == list.getLength() - 1) {
                System.out.println("]");
            } else {
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            //temp = temp.next;
        }
    }



}
```

When I first tried to do test inserting I go null pointer exceptions and then I tried to see why so I found out that when I'm in my testing class, the head is coming up null.

I tried checking to see if this happens in the insert method, but it is correctly updating the head while in that method. But when I go to the ListTest class the head is null. I can't find the issue at all.

Comment: What does `LinkedListBase` look like? Does it also have a field `head`? Did you declare the field `head` in both classes? Note that fields aren't overridden in java inheritence. So if you did you'll just end up with your subclass `DoublyLinkedList` having 2 `head` fields. (With one shadowing the other )

Comment: There is no reason to write `super();` in the constructor. It will call the base class's constructor by default. At what line are you getting the exception?

Comment: *First issue*, while you are utilizing a `LinkedListBase<Integer>` of generic type, however, the `LinkedListBase` class in the provided code is not generic. 

I modified it to `LinkedListBase<E>` in order to mathcup with the generic type of DoublyLinkedList seems to work for me

___________

*Second Issue*: also within your ListTest class, tyour seem to be printing `list1.head` after invokeing `testLinkedInsert`. 

Problem issue here is that the head property in your `DoublyLinkedList` class cannot be accessed as it is declared as `private`. ***change it to public***